# Calculated "Average" Column Shows Too Many Decimals

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I've got column where I'm using a formula to calculate the average of a few other columns. It keeps showing a bunch of decimals even with the decimals set to 2 on the column.

I've seen where some folks suggest to use the TEXT function to format the final value and others are suggesting using the ROUNDUP function. I just can't get the syntax right though and SharePoint won't accept my attempts.

If you want to use a formula inside another function what is the right syntax?

Example if I have the following:

```
=AVERAGE([Number One]), Two, [Number Three])
```

How do I limit the output to 2 decimal places? I've purposely included columns with spaces and columns without because that is what I'm faced with.

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using formula like:

```
=ROUND(AVERAGE([Number One]), Two, [Number Three]), 2)
```

**Documentations**:

1. [ROUND function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/round-function-b5e7cff8-5e61-4172-82f6-86308e403748)
2. [ROUNDUP function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/roundup-function-a92985d9-f99a-4ed4-9fd4-ad6e1d6f10b7)
3. [ROUNDDOWN function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rounddown-function-2ecb3677-7a76-4634-830f-512a92c1d62c)

**Note**:

1. Sometimes comma(`,`) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(`;`) instead of comma(`,`).
2. Use correct *display name* of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
3. Wrap column names inside `[]` if your column name has space in it. For example: `[My Column Name]`

Comment: That did it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you!